# Unused preconnect links (lighhouse warnings)

Tags: javascript, html, lighthouse

I'm trying to set some preconnected links in page's header. But Lighthouse is producing warnings as it was not used or something.

example of that warning:

> A preconnect  was found for "https://static.criteo.net" but was not used by the browser. Check that you are using the `crossorigin` attribute properly.

This is my link in html:

```html
<link href="https://static.criteo.net" rel="preconnect">
```

Answer (score 2):

Example syntax:

```
<link href="https://static.criteo.net" rel="preconnect" crossorigin>
```

This allows your browser to setup an early connection before an HTTP request is actually sent to the server. The assumption is you're getting something (font?, image(s)?) from the referenced link later.